# Merge data from two SQL tables to show in two TabPage

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datatable, tabcontrol

I have a simple register program in `WinForms` and instead of just displaying the records in the`dataGridView` I want to put the data that was inserted into the `textBox` into a`tabControl`. But what happens is that in addition to the `table` I've already created in`SQL server` for all client information, I'll have to create another `table` just for the contact information and then display them in`tabControl`(The general information in one`tabPage` and the contact information in another).

I would like to know how to connect the two tables created in SQL Server, since each record of each client is populated by the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE tblClientes (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Telefone varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Tipo varchar(255) NOT NULL, );

CREATE TABLE tblTelefone (
ID int NOT NULL,
Telefone varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID));


string strConn= "Data Source=X\\X;Initial Catalog=X;User id=X;Password=X;";
string strCommtblCli = "SELECT * FROM tblClientes ORDER BY ID"; //table com informações gerais 
string strCommtblCon = "SELECT * FROM tblTelefone ORDER BY ID"; //table de contato

SqlConnection objConn;
SqlCommand objComm;
SqlCommandBuilder cmdbldr;
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("tblClientes"); 
string strConn= "Data Source=X\\X;Initial Catalog=X;User id=X;Password=X;";
string strCommtblCli = "SELECT * FROM tblClientes ORDER BY ID"; //table com informações gerais 
string strCommtblCon = "SELECT * FROM tblTelefone ORDER BY ID"; //table de contato

SqlConnection objConn;

SqlCommand objComm;
SqlCommandBuilder cmdbldr;
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("tblClientes");

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void novoMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    alterarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    excluirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    groupBox1.Enabled = true;
    reset();
    txt_nome.Focus();
    txt_registro.Enabled = false;
}

private void bt_pfisica_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bt_pfisica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_tipo.Text = "F";
        txt_registro.Mask = "000,000,000-00";
    }
}

private void bt_pjuridica_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bt_pjuridica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_tipo.Text = "J";
        txt_registro.Mask = "00,000,000/0000-00";
    }
}

//BOTÃO PARA ALTERAR UM CADASTRO
private void alterarToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    novoMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    excluirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nenhum dado para editar!", "Alerta");
        fn_hab_opcoesMenu();
    }
    else
    {
        groupBox1.Enabled = true;
    }

}

//BOTÃO PARA EXCLUIR UM CADASTRO
private void excluirToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    novoMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    alterarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommtblCli, objConn);

    cmdbldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nenhum dado a excluir!", "Alerta");
    }
    else
    {
        int num_linha = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        dataSet.Tables["tblClientes"].Rows[num_linha].Delete();
        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblClientes");
    }
    reset();
}

//BOTÃO PARA SALVAR O CADASTRO
private void bt_salva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num_charTextTel = txt_telefone.Text.Length;
    int num_charMaskTel = txt_telefone.Mask.Length;

    int num_charTextReg = txt_registro.Text.Length;
    int num_charMaskReg = txt_registro.Mask.Length;

    if (txt_nome.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Campo nome de preenchimento obrigatório.", "Alerta!");
        txt_nome.Focus();
    }
    else if (num_charTextTel != num_charMaskTel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Campo telefone de preenchimento obrigatório.", "Alerta!");
        txt_telefone.Focus();
    }
    else if (txt_registro.Enabled == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Escolha o tipo de pessoa.", "Alerta!");
    }
    else if (num_charTextReg != num_charMaskReg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Campo registro de preenchimento obrigatório.", "Alerta!");
        txt_registro.Focus();
    }

    else
    {
        if (bt_pfisica.Checked)
        {
            txt_tipo.Text = "F";
        }
        else
        {
            txt_tipo.Text = "J";
        }

        if (novoMenuItem.Enabled)
        {
            incluir();

            Form1_Load_1(sender, e);
        }
        else if (alterarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled)
        {
            altera();

        }

        reset();
        groupBox1.Enabled = false;

    }
}


public void incluir()
{

    objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblCli, objConn);

    objComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblClientes (Nome,Telefone, Registro, Tipo) VALUES (@Nome, @Telefone,@Registro,@Tipo)";

    try
    {
        objConn.Open();

        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txt_nome.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txt_telefone.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registro", txt_registro.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", txt_tipo.Text);

        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblClientes");
        objComm.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        dataSet.Clear(); 
        objConn.Close();  

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void altera()
{
    try
    {
        objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblCli, objConn);
        cmdbldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        objConn.Open();

        string ID = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();

        objComm.CommandText = "UPDATE tblClientes SET Nome=@Nome,Telefone=@Telefone,Registro=@Registro,Tipo=@Tipo WHERE ID=" + ID;

        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txt_nome.Text); 
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txt_telefone.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registro", txt_registro.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", txt_tipo.Text);

        objComm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblClientes");
        dataSet.Clear();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblClientes"); 

        objConn.Close(); 

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}


private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    groupBox1.Enabled = false;

    objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblCli, objConn);
    objConn.Open();

    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommtblCli, objConn);

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblClientes"); 

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "tblClientes";

}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    txt_nome.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString();
    txt_telefone.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Telefone"].Value.ToString();
    txt_registro.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Registro"].Value.ToString();
    txt_tipo.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Tipo"].Value.ToString();

     if (txt_tipo.Text == "F") bt_pfisica.Checked = true;
     else  bt_pjuridica.Checked = true;

}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    objConn.Close();  
} 

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

private void novoMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    alterarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    excluirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    groupBox1.Enabled = true;
    reset();
    txt_nome.Focus();
    txt_registro.Enabled = false;
}

private void bt_pfisica_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bt_pfisica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_tipo.Text = "F";
        txt_registro.Mask = "000,000,000-00";
    }
}

private void bt_pjuridica_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bt_pjuridica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_tipo.Text = "J";
        txt_registro.Mask = "00,000,000/0000-00";
    }
}

//BOTÃO PARA ALTERAR UM CADASTRO
private void alterarToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    novoMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    excluirToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nenhum dado para editar!", "Alerta");
        fn_hab_opcoesMenu();
    }
    else
    {
        groupBox1.Enabled = true;
    }

}

//BOTÃO PARA EXCLUIR UM CADASTRO
private void excluirToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    novoMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    alterarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommtblCli, objConn);

    cmdbldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nenhum dado a excluir!", "Alerta");
    }
    else
    {
        int num_linha = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        dataSet.Tables["tblClientes"].Rows[num_linha].Delete();
        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblClientes");
    }
    reset();
}

//BOTÃO PARA SALVAR O CADASTRO
private void bt_salva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num_charTextTel = txt_telefone.Text.Length;
    int num_charMaskTel = txt_telefone.Mask.Length;

    int num_charTextReg = txt_registro.Text.Length;
    int num_charMaskReg = txt_registro.Mask.Length;

    if (txt_nome.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Campo nome de preenchimento obrigatório.", "Alerta!");
        txt_nome.Focus();
    }
    else if (num_charTextTel != num_charMaskTel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Campo telefone de preenchimento obrigatório.", "Alerta!");
        txt_telefone.Focus();
    }
    else if (txt_registro.Enabled == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Escolha o tipo de pessoa.", "Alerta!");
    }
    else if (num_charTextReg != num_charMaskReg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Campo registro de preenchimento obrigatório.", "Alerta!");
        txt_registro.Focus();
    }

    else
    {
        if (bt_pfisica.Checked)
        {
            txt_tipo.Text = "F";
        }
        else
        {
            txt_tipo.Text = "J";
        }

        if (novoMenuItem.Enabled)
        {
            incluir();

            Form1_Load_1(sender, e);
        }
        else if (alterarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled)
        {
            altera();

        }

        reset();
        groupBox1.Enabled = false;

    }
}


public void incluir()
{

    objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblCli, objConn);

    objComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblClientes (Nome,Telefone, Registro, Tipo) VALUES (@Nome, @Telefone,@Registro,@Tipo)";

    try
    {
        objConn.Open();

        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txt_nome.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txt_telefone.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registro", txt_registro.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", txt_tipo.Text);

        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblClientes");
        objComm.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        dataSet.Clear(); 
        objConn.Close();  

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void altera()
{
    try
    {
        objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblCli, objConn);
        cmdbldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        objConn.Open();

        string ID = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();

        objComm.CommandText = "UPDATE tblClientes SET Nome=@Nome,Telefone=@Telefone,Registro=@Registro,Tipo=@Tipo WHERE ID=" + ID;

        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txt_nome.Text); 
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txt_telefone.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registro", txt_registro.Text);
        objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", txt_tipo.Text);

        objComm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblClientes");
        dataSet.Clear();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblClientes"); 

        objConn.Close(); 

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}


private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    groupBox1.Enabled = false;

    objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblCli, objConn);
    objConn.Open();

    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommtblCli, objConn);

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblClientes"); 

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "tblClientes";

}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    txt_nome.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString();
    txt_telefone.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Telefone"].Value.ToString();
    txt_registro.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Registro"].Value.ToString();
    txt_tipo.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Tipo"].Value.ToString();

    if (txt_tipo.Text == "F") bt_pfisica.Checked = true;
    else  bt_pjuridica.Checked = true;

}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    objConn.Close();  
}
```

Comment: It would help if you show the structure of the `tblClientes` and `tblTelefone`. Presumably there is some common field that you can use to link a row in one table to a row in the other table, but that is not possible to tell from what you have posted. Something like this: `CREATE TABLE tblClientes (ID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Nome nvarchar(100), Telefone nvarchar(50), Registro bit, Tipo char(1))`

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: it will also help if you include the `tblTelefone` definition.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question